# PyCharm problem with console emulator - cannot type into emulated console

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I have recently experienced problems with PyCharm with this build info:

[image: Build info]

The problem with the emulator is that you cannot type into emulator console when using user input. The python script itself works when you turn off console emulation a run your script in python console instead. But running through emulator would be more comfortable for me as for others. The error you receive is this one:

> Zadej pozici: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Engeto/python/STUFF/1D_piskvorky/1D_pisk.py", line 79, in 
> piskvorky_1d()
> File "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Engeto/python/STUFF/1D_piskvorky/1D_pisk.py", line 70, in piskvorky_1d
> hrac_vstup= int(input("Zadej pozici: "))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Which means that python received an empty value for `int()` I suppose, but when you try to type some characters instead of a number:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ssss'

The emulator sees that you type characters instead of numbers. Please let me know if someone came across this problem and what was a solution for you, maybe this could help others with finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim that you cannot type into the emulated console is incorrect.  You entered strings that are not valid arguments for `input`.  The error messages are correct.  They are the same as when one enters the same directly into interactive python.

```
Python 3.9.0a3+ (heads/master:46874c26ee, Jan 30 2020, 20:04:52) [MSC v.1900 32
bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = int(input('Enter number: '))
Enter number:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> s = int(input('Enter number: '))
Enter number: xxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xxxx'
```

They are also the same as when one runs the same code from a file.  `input` returns a string.  Reread the part of the int doc about string arguments.

```
If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
>>> int('0b100', base=0)
4
```

Neither '' nor 'ssss' represent string literals in base 10.

Comment: The error message is OK, i am aware that i cant treat string as int but thats not the issue. The issue is that its not possible to write down the numbers in to the console. You see, when i physically type numbers they wont appear in the console itself and the input is treated as empty string in further execution. But when i try type chars like "sss" (just to see if i am able to write into the conosole) they still wont appear in the emulated console, but they the input is not treated as empty and you see this error in further execution - wich is OK becouse you are giving string into int.

Comment: OK. My experience is only with IDLE, not Pycharm, so I could not understand 'wont appear' as you now explained it.  I would try separating the call and adding a print -- `s = input('# ')`, `print(s)`, and `h = int(s)` to make sure that the input return is empty.